# Gradle nested multi-projects with project compile dependencies

Tags: build, dependencies, gradle, multi-project

I have an identical problem to this [Gradle Multi-Module Project Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013597/gradle-multi-module-project-setup) but I have to use project compile dependencies to build and cannot use the library(jar) dependencies solution that was given as a solution in the above question.

```
Root
|__ P1
|   |_ PP1
|   |_ PP2
|
|__ P2
   |_PP3
   |_PP4
```

PP1, PP2, PP3 and PP4 are sub-projects and each have their own build.gradle files; P1 and P2 also have build.gradle and settings.gradle files.

How can I declare PP1 as a compile dependency in PP3's build.gradle file?

```
apply plugin: 'java' 
dependencies {
    compile('P1:PP1') //does not work
    compile group: 'P1', name: 'PP1', version: '0.1' // jar library dependency not an option

    compile('{ant_target}')? //follow up question - an ant target as a dependency
}
```

I'm running Gradle v1.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set up a gradle project with more than 2 levels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299004/is-it-possible-to-set-up-a-gradle-project-with-more-than-2-levels)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

A build can only have a single `settings.gradle` file. Assuming `settings.gradle` is in the root directory and includes projects like so:

```
include "P1:PP1"
```

You can add a compile dependency like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile(project(":P1:PP1"))
}
```

For more information, see the "Multi-Project Builds" chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#javaMultiProject).

Comment: Thanks! On a related question, is it possible to have an Ant target declared as a dependency in the build.gradle dependencies closure?  

Scenario: P2's build.gradle file imports P2's build.xml; "myAntTask" is a target in build.xml; the project settings.gradle has `include 'P1:PP1', 'P2'`; I can execute P2's "myAntTask" ant target using Gradle.  

Sticking with my compile dependency requirement, how can I declare "myAntTask" as a compile dependency in P1's build.gradle?  
I'm slowly converting my Ant built project to Gradle while also adding new Gradle projects

Comment: Sounds like you are confusing task dependencies and artifact dependencies.

Comment: Didn't answer the question "How can I declare PP1 as a compile dependency in PP3's build.gradle file?". This solution only shows P1 and PP1.

Comment: Settings file 'C:\Workspace\MyDependentProject\settings.gradle' line: 24
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'MyDependentProject'.
Project with path 'DependencyProject' could not be found.

Comment: late to the party, but for anyone new coming along: Gradle 4.10 now supports nested (composite) builds, so we can now have a build within a build within a build etc, each with their own settings file

Comment: Hey @AndyDingfelder, when should we prefer a multi projects having multiple settings.gradle over simple multi module build with only one settings.gradle? What is the idea behind multi project build, any usecase?

Comment: @AndyDingfelder really? it seems still only single `settings.gradle` is allowed?