# Is it possible to set up a gradle project with more than 2 levels?

Tags: gradle

We have been using gradle for about a year and have been somewhat successful with it. A number of features are still a little opaque, but we are getting there. I am not sure I am going about solving the problem correctly, so I will go ahead and ask the question:

All the examples that I have seen for gradle have a root project and one level of sub-projects. For a number of reasons, we would like to consolidate our git projects. All of these are gradle projects, some of which have gradle sub-projects. What we want to end up with is essentially a multi-level gradle structure. We do not want to alter the gradle setup for all those projects and instead would like to have a top level gradle that manages all the projects and corresponding subprojects. My first attempt showed that I cannot have a controlling build.gradle that orchestrates all of the projects and subprojects. Am I doing something wrong? Am I following and inherently broken paradigm?

Here is a sample structure for what I want to do:

```
Top Project
  build.gradle
  Project
    build.gradle
    Sub Project
      build.gradle
      src
    Sub Project
      ...
  Project
    ...
```

Thank you and I hope I did not miss some obvious explanation in the documentation.

Comment: After doing some more reading, it looks like what I should do is use the GradleBuild task: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:external_build

Comment: `GradleBuild` is the best you can do today. The real deal (aggregating builds) is a planned feature.

Answer (score 23):

I would simply put the following in TopProject/settings.gradle:

```
include 'Project1:SubProject1'
include 'Project1:SubProject2'
include 'Project2:SubProject1'
...
```

The only change required to the projects you currently have is to remove settings.gradle files from them as you can only have one setting.gradle file per project structure.

Comment: Well, it may be that our builds are not ideally set, but that did not work quite right. GradleBuild seems to be doing the trick along with some dynamic task generation.

Comment: This will lead to two level 'flattened' project structure, NOT to a multilevel structure. If you open this in IDE you will see all projects listed instead of grouped.

Comment: One should add that dependencies to such nested projectes have the form `implementation project(":Project1:SubProject1")`

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem. The simplest solution was to configure gradle by adding projects in the $root/settings.gradle file similar to the Erdi's answer. However, I managed to automatically add all subprojects. The logic will simply go through my directory structure and find all directories that contain `build.gradle` and add them as subprojects.

Here is how to do it:

- Make sure you don't have any other `settings.gradle` but the root one
- The content of the root settings.gradle file should be:

```js
fileTree('.') {
  include '**/build.gradle'
  exclude 'build.gradle' // Exclude the root build file.
}.collect { relativePath(it.parent).replace(File.separator, ':') }
 .each { include(it) }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: A follow-up for anyone implementing this method, Gradle actually tries to run tasks in the parent sub-directory.  Even when it only has sub-folders for sub-projects.

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin version of `settings.gradle.kts`

```
fileTree(".") {
    include("**/build.gradle")
    include("**/build.gradle.kts")
    exclude("buildSrc/**")
    exclude("build.gradle.kts")
}.map {
    relativePath(it.parent)
        .replace(File.separator, ":")
}.forEach {
    include(it)
}
```

Instead of adding it manually like this (like `Intellij Idea` suggests):

```
include("modules:core")
findProject(":modules:core")?.name = "core"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working quite well:

```
ext{
  buildPrefix = "build"
  allProjects = ["P1", "P2"]
}

def createTasks(String prefix) {
  def newTasks = allProjects.each {
    def pName ->
      def tName = "$prefix$pName"
      tasks.add(name: tName, type: GradleBuild) {
        dir = pName
        tasks = [ prefix ]
      }
  }
}

createTasks(buildPrefix)

ext {
  buildTasks = tasks.findAll{ t -> t.name.startsWith(buildPrefix) }
}

task build(dependsOn: buildTasks) {}
```

I can just add the other tasks that I want to expose at the top level.

Thanks for the pointers.