# How to include another root project in settings.gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a 2 root projects in gradle one main root project1 from where I invoke gradle build and has settings.gradle which includes subprojects to build

Another root project2 where I have settings.gradle which includes subprojects to build

Rootproject1
build.gradle
settings.gradle

Rootproject2
build.gradle
settings.gradle

I want to inlcude Rootproject2 in my Rootproject1 settings.gradle file so that from Rootproject1 (gradle build) should build Rootproject1 as well as  Rootproject2

include/inlcudeFlat -- it is relative to rootproject

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set up a gradle project with more than 2 levels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299004/is-it-possible-to-set-up-a-gradle-project-with-more-than-2-levels)

Comment: Mentioned approach in the above link does not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be one `settings.gradle` which will be placed inside the primary root folder and you will need to write:

```
include ':Rootproject1',
        ':Rootproject2'
```

Then, in the `build.gradle` file of Rootproject1, you will need to write:

```
dependencies {
 implementation project(path: ':Rootproject2')
}
```

[Updated on Jan 23, 2019] Something like following:

```
Root 
|------ Rootproject1
|
|------ Rootproject2
|
|------ settings.gradle
```

Comment: By default all paths included in settings.gradle are relative to root project hence above approach also fails

Comment: Yes, you need to add Rootproject1 & Rootproject2 inside a master-like Root folder. I have updated my answer with a graph to imagine my thought.